# C# LINQ to SQL procedures to JSON nested object

Tags: c#, json, model-view-controller, linq-to-sql

My goal is to take stored procedure from SQL and is result use for web service response in JSON format, and I have a lot of stored procedure which reading in MVC with LINQ to SQL.

**Question is how to make JSON which have same structure as object (of stored procedure) which is created by LINQ?**

At the moment all what is get is flat array of keys, and values which return same structure as output of procedure.

```
public Stream GetFinalCustom(int top, int accID)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(...))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("_qryCustomObject", con))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@top", 40);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@accID", 5);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
            System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
            List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
            Dictionary<string, object> row;
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                {
                    row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
                }
                rows.Add(row);
            }
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            return new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(serializer.Serialize(rows)));
        }
    }
}
```

Which return JSON like this

```
[{"key":value,"key":value,...}]
```

But what I wish is

```
{
  "key": value,
  "key": value,
  .
  .
  .
  },
   "table1": 
  {
    "key": value
    "key": value
  },
  "table2": 
  {
    "key": value
    "key": value
  }
}
```

Is MVC have some ability to make JSON with all structure by it self by using models, ets... any idea while be appreciated.

Comment: You mention LINQ but the question has *NO* LINQ code at all. You posted an ADO.NET stored procedure call that populates a DataTable. There are no objects to serialize to Json, just table rows. What objects are you talking about? Where does LINQ come into this? What do you want your JSON text to look like?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos ... oh sorry will update calling method

Comment: If you want to control the layout of the generated JSON you'll need to take control of the process. Eg. use JSON.NET's serialiser, or if not possible using that then manually converting (JSON.NET's LINQ to JSON would be my choice). (Generally serialisation support on types provides a quick and simple solution but little control.)